# MSAL.NET - Cache a access / refresh token from an existing JWT bearer token

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I've got a web app where you can add an integration with your MS calendar. This uses MSAL.NET, and the auth code flow, so the user grants access to some scopes to their calendar, and MSAL.NET caches the access / refresh tokens so that we can later make calls to the MS Graph API.

We also have a mobile app, and need to offer the same functionality for users to authenticate their MS calendar. So, we use a library that does the full auth code flow on mobile. This code ends up with a valid refresh token, access token and JWT token.

I need to be able to pass this token to my backend, and then cache this in my MSAL.NET token cache so that it can be used at a later point when we need to sync to the calendar.

It's working out what to do in the MSAL.NET side that's causing me pain. What I used to do, and what used to work in an older version of MSAL.NET, was to pass the JWT, and use `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` to acquire a token on behalf of the user.

Here's the code:

```cs
  public async Task<ActionResult> CacheTokens(string idToken)
    {

    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl)
        .Build();
    

    var tokenCacheProvider = ((MuTokenCacheProvider)_cacheProvider);
    tokenCacheProvider.Initialize(app.UserTokenCache, myUserId);
                
    var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(idToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
    
    string[] scopes = {"email", "Calendars.ReadWrite"};
    
    var result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion)
        .ExecuteAsync();
    
    }
```

Unfortunately, the docs state that this does not store the refresh token now (which is what I see). I can't work out how to take my existing JWT / refresh tokens, and persist them in the MSAL.NET cache so that my app can then use them.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

I’ve abandoned this, nothing seems to
Work, it seems that if you have an existing refresh token msal doesn’t make it easy to cache manually.

Instead, my mobile app uses a web view to invoke the web app, so you effectively auth on the web site and that keeps msal.net happy.

Comment: I totally appreciate why you might negative vote this, but I'm just being honest - in my opinion there wasn't a way I could find so I had to look for an alternative. I'm still actively watching this thread though so hopefully someone will shed some light on tihs